# AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'plot_tree'

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to plot the first decision tree of XGBoost and I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'plot_tree'
```

This is how I am trying to plot the tree

```
import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBClassifier,plot_tree
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df_train = pd.read_csv("File.csv ")
y = df_train.loc[:, 'CLASS']
X= df_train.loc[:, 's1': 's320']
model = XGBClassifier(
    scale_pos_weight=1,
    learning_rate=0.009,
    colsample_bytree=0.4,
    subsample=0.8,
    objective='binary:logistic',
    n_estimators=1100,
    reg_alpha=0.3,
    max_depth=4,
    gamma=0,
    use_label_encoder=False)
model.fit(X, y)
plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

I didn't find similar issue in the forum, anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: that errors tends to come from versioning, please verify in the documentation of the version you have installed that this is available.

Comment: as I can see from here https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/plotting.py it is available. the version I use is 1.3.3.